# How to load latest contacts from iPhone using ABAddressBook when user press home button

Tags: ios, swift, abaddressbook

I am loading contacts using ABAdderessBook framework, it is working fine. Suppose I have a 20,0000 contacts I am loading in tabelview. Suppose I pressed the Home button and add some contacts then how to get only those contacts?

Comment: Have you read the [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744)?

Answer (score 0):

Use startObserveChangesWithCallback